# cvxpy + mosek: The lower bound specified is not a number (nan)

Tags: numerical-methods, scientific-computing, cvxpy, convex-optimization, mosek

In below code snippet I am trying to do a very simple linear regression using cvxpy and mosek solver

```
weight = df2['weight'].to_numpy()
A = df2[ regressors ].to_numpy()
x = cp.Variable(len(regressors ));
R = df2['y'].to_numpy()
cost = cp.sum_squares( A @ x - R)
print(A.shape, x.shape, R.shape)          # here it prints (134882, 8) (8,) (134882,)
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cost), 
           [x >= 0])
```

but I keep getting below error.

```
Error: rescode.err_lower_bound_is_a_nan(1390): The lower bound specified is not a number (nan).
```

I have checked the manual: https://docs.mosek.com/latest/pythonapi/response-codes.html#mosek.rescode.err_lower_bound_is_a_nan  but what exactly am I missing?

Comment: Your input data contain NANs is the best bet. Or a bug in cvxpy. Btw why do you minimize sum of squares? Minimizing the norm is better.

Comment: @ErlingMOSEK forive my ignorance, why is it that minimizing the norm is better than minimize sum of squares?

Comment: The norm behaves like a linear function ond is better scaled. In any case cvxpy will convert the problem into s norm problem before sending it to   Mosek. Mosek prefers the norm form.

Comment: @ErlingMOSEK You have to use cp.norm explicitly.

Comment: So try: cost = cp.norm( A @ x - R)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's hard to answer this question without having a reproducible example with your data.

Your python code seems fine, so I believe the problem is in your data: if I must take a guess, I assume you have `NaNs` somewhere in your data which causes the failure.

I'm not sure if cvxpy and mosek handle nans at all, so it's a good idea to verify your data integrity before using them.

Comment: hah indeed.... there is a nan. i wish they give a more clear error message.

Comment: Cvxpy should check for NANs if a better message should be produced.